# How to make the onchange event start programatically?

Tags: jquery, html

When the page loads or in the `$(document).ready` I want to make the `onchange` event of a `select` element to be launched because the page is in update mode. There are non-database select elements and database select elements , but the database select elements depend on those non-database select elements :

```
<select id="province" name="province" onchange="rafraichirRegions($(this).val());"> ... // this is non-database select element
<select id="region_" name="faritra" required> ... // this is a database select element
```

So when the page loads I want to select an option in the non-database select element , then launch its `onchange` event. How to do that ?

Comment: You can get value of select drop box and pass it to `rafraichirRegions` function and call that function inside `document.ready`

Comment: Why didnt I think about that !? Yes I will try that !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as simple as:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#province').change();
});
```

Comment: but this will trigger the event

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger the change event when document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#province").on("change",function(){
// change code 

}).trigger("change");
});
```

note: Remove inner html coding onchange="rafraichirRegions($(this).val() bcoz it wil also triggered